# On the set equality $ \{ x \in A | f(x) + g(x) < c \} = \bigcup_{q \in Q} ( \{ x \in A | f(x) < q \} \cap \{x \in A | g(x) < c - q \} )$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I thought I understood a proof of a set equality in class but I am now having some doubts.

Take a measurable set $A$ and two measurable functions $f,g : A \rightarrow R$ then $\{ x \in A | f(x) + g(x) < c \} = \{ x \in A | f(x) < c - g(x) \}$.

We notice that from the density of $Q$ in $R$ we have $f(x) < c - g(x) \iff \exists q \in Q| f(x) < q < c - g(x) \iff \exists q \in Q | (f(x) < q \ \And \ g(x) < c - q)$

So it follows that

$$ \{ x \in A | f(x) + g(x) < c \} = \bigcup_{q \in Q} ( \{ x \in A | f(x) < q   \} \cap \{x \in A | g(x) < c - q  \}) $$

This is where I am having problems, By making some simple examples I see that it's true, and I understand that if we had a simple chain of implications instead of if and only ifs this would not work but I feel like I am missing some simple extra justification coming from the countable union definition to "get it".

Maybe someone could kindly provide a simpler example of the same kind of equality so it could finally click for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the general definition of the union:
$$\bigcup \limits_{i \in I} A_i = \{ x \mid \exists i \in I: x \in A_i\}.$$

In this case $I = \mathbb{Q}$ and $A_i = \{x \in A \mid (f(x) < i) \wedge (g(x) < c - i)\}$.

Comment: But how do I know there is no extra element?

Comment: I mean I know that an element of $B = \{x \in A | f(x) + g(x) < c \}$ also belongs to $A = \bigcup_{q \in Q} ( \{ x \in A | f(x) < q   \} \cap \{x \in A | g(x) < c - q  \}$ but what about an element of $A$ belonging to $B$.