# Prove ${\{x\in E \ | \ f(x) + g(x)<c}\} = \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q} ({\{x\in E \ | \ g(x) < c - q}\} \cap {\{x\in E \ | \ f(x) < q}\})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Reading through the proof of measurablity of f+g if f and g are measurable functions, I faced with the following equality without proof or explanation:

> ${\{x\in E \ | \ f(x) + g(x)<c}\} = \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q} ({\{x\in E \ | \ g(x) < c - q}\}  \cap {\{x\in E \ | \ f(x) < q}\})$

May it seems intuitively true as $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, but even a bit long attempt I can't prove it rigorously!

I also have got same as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715540/on-the-set-equality-x-in-a-fx-gx-c-bigcup-q-in-q-x);

> $f(x) < c - g(x) \iff \exists q \in \mathbb Q \ : \ f(x) < q < c - g(x) \iff \exists q \in \mathbb Q \ : \ (f(x) < q \ \text {and} \ g(x) < c - q),$

But my question is why [by proving with mathematics!] denseness of $\mathbb Q$ is enough that it could be 'big-enough' to be 'replaced' by $\mathbb R$ especially when we know that measure of $\mathbb Q$ is zero but measure of $\mathbb R$ is not?

Comment: The point of using $\mathbb Q$ is that it's a countable set, and measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra. For what it's worth, it's not particularly time-efficient to ponder over the extreme basics of measure theory. There are a lot more stranger phenomena in the later chapters of whatever book you're reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ s.t. $f(x)+g(x)<c$. In particular, $f(x)<c-g(x)$, and thus, by density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ there is $q\in \mathbb Q$ s.t. $$f(x)<q<c-g(x),$$
what gives you the inclusion $\subset $. For the other one (i.e. $\supset$), if there is a $q\in \mathbb Q$ s.t. $f(x)<q$ and $g(x)<c-q$, then $f(x)+g(x)<c$.